# Insert images dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a custom receiver for Chrome Cast. My sender sends me a picture to chromecast, precise positioning this image according to the coordinates sent by the sender.

index.html:

```
<div id="interacao" class="interacao">
    <h1 id="h1texto">Adicione suas mídias pelo celular!</h1>
    <video id="vdo"></video>
</div>
```

manipulacaoElemento.js:

```
function insertImg(element){
    elementoAInserir = document.createElement("img");
    elementoAInserir.id = element.idImg;
    elementoAInserir.src = element.url;
    elementoAInserir.style.width = element.widthImagem +'px';
    elementoAInserir.style.height = element.heightImagem +'px';
    elementoAInserir.style.left = element.posicao.x+'px';
    elementoAInserir.style.top = element.posicao.y+'px';
    $('.interacao').html(elementoAInserir);
}
```

The image is loaded, but not at the position that the sender sent, but instead at the position 0, 0.
Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `elementoAInserir.style.position = 'absolute';`

```js
function insertImg(element) {
  elementoAInserir = document.createElement("img");
  elementoAInserir.id = element.idImg;
  elementoAInserir.src = element.url;
  elementoAInserir.style.position = 'absolute';
  elementoAInserir.style.width = element.widthImagem + 'px';
  elementoAInserir.style.height = element.heightImagem + 'px';
  elementoAInserir.style.left = element.posicao.x + 'px';
  elementoAInserir.style.top = element.posicao.y + 'px';
  $('.interacao').html(elementoAInserir);
}

insertImg({
  idImg: '...',
  url: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar',
  widthImagem: 100,
  heightImagem: 100,
  posicao: {
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="interacao" class="interacao">
  <h1 id="h1texto">Adicione suas mídias pelo celular!</h1>
  <video id="vdo"></video>
</div>
```